# Qual a forma correta no retorno do tratamento

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde amigo, estou com um tratamento errado e gostaria de solucionar. Não estou conseguindo visualizar as informações.

## Linha de código

```
<option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_vendedor']; ?>"><?php echo $results[1]["nome_vendedor"]; ?></option>
```

Comment: Quais as informações você visualiza em cada um? Poderia montar tabelas em sua pergunta para facilitar a compreensão?

Comment: Se você esta visualizando os registros de 1 a 4 corretamente, então, me parece que não há nada errado com o select, mas com os dados. Como você esta usando INNER JOIN então é necessário que as referências dos itens existam em todas as tabelas envolvidas no SELECT. Se você substituir por LEFT JOIN você garante que CADASTRO_CLIENTES virá, claro se existir,  independente se o registro de ligação existe nas outras ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolvendo assim:
Isso acontece que eu estava pegando sempre o próximo índice, então quando chegava no último índice, ele jogava pra +1, e esse índice não existia.

```
<option value="<?php echo $results[0]['id_revenda']; ?>"><?php echo $results[0]["nome_revenda"]; ?></option>
```